# formula compiles in PB sandbox but not in production

Tags: formula, process-builder

I have a formula field in a PB as the criteria to update a field. It works fine in sandbox but in Prod I get an error.

The PB should update the case if the Type changes from the L3 value.
[image: ProdvsSandbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustrating! Try and remove the formula and see if you can save. My suspicion is that it's an error on another formula in the process builder.